# Joint probability heatmap

Tags: python, probability, heatmap, gaussian

I need to create a heatmap cnetered around x_0 = 0.5 from a Gaussian distribution `np.random.normal(theta1, theta2, size=1)` where theta1 is the mean and theta2 is the standard deviation. With x_0 = 0.5, the Gaussian equation is `(1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp((x-x**2-0.25)/2)`. The heatmap is to be in terms of theta1 and theta2. I've tried running a nested for loop, I've tried two for loops, but I can't seem to make anything work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I've tried running a nested for loop, I've tried two for loops" - what _exactly_ have you tried and what exactly didn't work? Please post a [mcve] and any error messages you got.

Comment: Are you using a charting library?